# Parsing Nested JSON and wondering how to avoid creating a class structure

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a nested JSON and when parsing all answers I am getting online suggest creating a class structure to fit the JSON and then extracting the data. Is there anyway I can store the data from the JSON directly into a nested Array List? The JSON structure might change overtime and I want to avoid having to alter the Java Object I create every time that happened. I am trying to use GSON for parsing at the moment but that isn't mandatory.

Comment: Since JSON is primarily key-value based, you might be better off mapping to nested `LinkedHashMap<String,Object>`s

Comment: @HankD A LinkedHashMap would work as well. Can I get some help on how to parse the JSON into one?

Comment: I've not used GSON, but it looks like this might work: `Map<String, Object> parsed = gson.fromJson(nestedJSON , LinkedHashMap.class);`.